# '\' at the end of row or line give split() error

Tags: python, escaping

```
code="""
[--]
{start}
\ok\
"waw"
the-end
"""
for i in code.split('\n') :
    print i

Result: 

[--]
{start}
\ok"waw"
the-end
```

I don't have access the the code as it's typed by user. the '\' at the end of \ok\ give me the wrong result. How can i split() correctly ?

Comment: `\n` is used for newline but when ' \' is encountered after ok it is escaped and newline is missed

Comment: Do you mean the user modifies your actual script to give input?

Comment: Use `os.linesep` instead of `\n`

Comment: Yes, but how can i do to fix it ? the code variable is coming from other end let say from the other part of the world, where he can type anything through the UI . So my only job is to make it as a list of whatever inside the variable.

Comment: @0decimal0 i tried os.linesep but still not working. as "for i in code.split(os.linesep)" . any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as was mentioned in the comments, that `\\` in a string literal followed by a newline will escape that newline, so in fact the value of `code` is already

```
[--]
{start}
\ok"waw"
the-end
```

You can refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for some more info on string literals in Python.

with no newline between `ok` and `"waw"`. The problem actually doesn't lie with your code at all, but with your sample input. You say you don't have access to the 'code' as the user will modify it - I can only assume you don't mean the user modifies the program to give input. My suggestion for how to take input is to have the user supply a separate file. This way, the string will be interpreted as a stream of characters and that alone, and Python won't try to do any escaping. For simplicity, I have hardcoded the filename, but it would probably also be a good idea eventually to make this flexible (take input from stdin, let the user supply the filename, etc..).

The file `input.txt` contains:

```
[--]
{start}
\ok\
"waw"
the-end
```

The code:

```
import sys
with open("input.txt", "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

As expected, the code ouputs

```
[--]
{start}
\ok\
"waw"
the-end
```

Presumably you want to do some more with the lines, as this just replicated the input.